# Is there an additive version of "Power.thy" in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

In Isabelle, I have defined a function `f:'a -> nat` where `'a` is some algebraic structure that extends a monoid (i.e. a group, semiring, ring, integral domain, field, ...).

I would like to use the output of this function as "coefficients" for my type `'a` in other constructs. That is, if `x:'a` and `n:nat`, I would like to be able to use some operation `·:'a -> nat -> 'a` that allows me to tell Isabelle that `n·x = x + x + ... + x`.

By searching a bit, I found the "[Power.thy](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/library/HOL/HOL/Power.html)" theory and, in a sense, it does what I want. However, it does it for the "multiplicative version" of my problem. This is an issue if I want to change `'a` for e.g. the integers. Using it would mean that instead of computing `n·x`, Isabelle would do `x^n`. Is there an analogous version to "[Power.thy](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/library/HOL/HOL/Power.html)" that does what I want? Or are there any other ways to circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any predefined constant that implements such an operation, but it can easily be implemented by iterating addition, e.g., using `comppow` on `nat`:

```
definition scale :: "nat => 'a => 'a" where
  "scale a n = ((plus a) ^^ n) 0"
```

where `plus` refers to the addition operation of your structure and `0` is the neutral element. If you are using the arithmetic type classes from Isabelle/HOL, you should add the sort constraint `'a :: monoid` to `scale`'s type.

There is also a type class operation `scaleR` in `Complex_Main` that implements such a coefficient scaling operation, but it allows `real` numbers, not only `nat`s, so your structure might not satisfy all the required axioms (type class `real_vector`).

Comment: Great! "compow" was exactly what I needed. I was afraid I might need to prove some extra things about it, but so far it has worked fine without extra theorems. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A quite idiomatic way to express this is multiplication and »of_nat«:

```
context semiring_1
begin

definition scale :: "nat ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a"
  where "scale n = times (of_nat n)"

lemma [simp]:
  "scale 0 a = 0"
  "scale (Suc n) a = a + scale n a"
  by (simp_all add: scale_def algebra_simps)

lemma
  "((plus a) ^^ n) 0 = scale n a"
  by (induct n) (simp_all)

end
```